# Reading XML file containing SQL statements that require variables from VB.NET program

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, variables

I have a program written in VB.NET and I wrote it with all my SQL statements hard-coded into the program. I wanted to try to store all my queries externally in an XML file so that changes can be made to the SQL (if needed) without having the go into the code and rebuild the program every single time.

The part that is complicating things is that the SQL statements require variables to be added to it for it to run properly.

For example:

> SELECT name_first, name_last, email_id FROM & eventName

With `eventName` being a variable in the program.

When I set up the XML file, I tried both of the following:

```
    <Data>
        <LoadSaves>
              <SQLStatement><![CDATA[SELECT name_first, name_last, email_id FROM &eventName&]]></SQLStatement>
        </LoadSaves>
    </Data>
```

and

```
    <Data>
        <LoadSaves>
              <SQLStatement><![CDATA["SELECT name_first, name_last, email_id FROM" & eventName]]></SQLStatement>
        </LoadSaves>
    </Data>
```

I needed the CDATA because without it, special characters would sometimes make it act weird.

My problem is that the program doesn't do any substituting of variables because in both methods, the program pulls the entire thing as a string.

Using the first method, I was able to just put some code in that would search for `&eventName&` and replaces it with the variable I need in there. This method worked perfectly but then defeats the purpose of having the SQL externally for easy modification, because if all of a sudden I need `attendeeName` instead of `eventName`, then I can change it in the XML file but then I would still need to change the code to look for `&attendeeName&` instead and substitute accordingly.

Is there any way I can handle this in a more dynamic way instead of having everything hard coded. Like I said, I want to be able to have my SQL in a separate file for easy modification if needed without having to touch the code, but with keeping in mind that each of my SQL statements require variables to be added to them before they can run.

Comment: I would not shoot down your hopes, but suppose that you need to add add another where condition to that query. How do you handle it without touching the code? And this is just the tip of the problems that you could encounter when your program evolve. I think you're entering a blind alley.

Comment: Adding variables to a SQL string is the wrong way to do this anyway.  You should learn how to use prepared statements.  Otherwise, you could have the ["Little Bobby Tables" problem](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What are you doing that made you think “store all my queries externally in an XML file” was going to help?

Answer (score 2):

1: This is a bad idea - someone can mess up your program or even find easy ways to hack it.

2: Your are concatenating strings which you cannot do at run-time, only design-time.

3: Don't build SQL Statements using concatenation, it can be hacked or broken easily. You should parameterize your SQL like so:

```
SELECT name_first, name_last, email_id FROM @EventName
```

And then when you run your command you use the `AddWithParamter` and add your parameter and value.

```
cmd.AddWithParameter("@EventName","Your value here")
```